# Converting PNG32 file to PNG8 without losing alpha channel

Tags: graphics, png

I'm using Linux and have no access to any of Adobe's 'fancy' programs.

I'm trying to convert an existing PNG32 image with alpha channel to PNG8. I have tried the following methods:

- `convert original.png PNG8:new.png` - Horribly distorts the image and preserving only binary alpha (Not Indexed alpha)
- GIMP - Fails as well, but produces better quality (good color quantizer) than ImageMagick.
- `pngcrush -rem alla -reduce -brute original.png new.png` - Made the image smaller but didn't take quantization into account (Image has less than 256 colors), so output was still PNG32.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PHP script does the trick with libgd:

```
<?PHP

if(!isset($argv[1]) || !is_readable($argv[1])) {
    echo "Creates an 8-bit PNG from a 32-bit PNG\n\n";
    echo "Usage:\n";
    echo "\t" . $argv[0] . " input.png > output.png\n";
    echo "\t" . $argv[0] . " input.png output.png\n";
    die();
}

$inFile = $argv[1];
$outFile = $argv[2] or STDOUT;

$inImage = imagecreatefrompng($inFile);
$outImage = imagecreate(imagesx($inImage), imagesy($inImage));

imagecopy($outImage, $inImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($inImage), imagesy($inImage));

imagepng($outImage, $outFile);
```

Dump that into a file and run it as:

```
php convert.php input.png output.png
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but this recently bit me on a web project I'm working on.

I used [pngnq](http://pngnq.sourceforge.net/) for batch conversion and my PNG8 have never looked better. In fact, with the highest sampling rate (`-s 1`) the results are nearly indistinguishable from a full PNG32.

Comment: What a useful link, thanks! I've been looking for such a tool for some time. Tested pngnq and it produces an excellent result, small file and smooth alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Your distro may include [pngquant](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngquant.html).  If you can't find it with yum / apt-get, go to the web site.  I think this is your best bet.

If you're having issues with pngquant, you can try [pngout](http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm), but it's a long shot.  I've heard it does a good job retaining the alpha channel, but can be slow.  Possibly the slowness people experience is because the default 'strategy' is 'Extreme' which the author admits is slow.

It's a windows program, but there are linux ports (supposedly), but the link on the pngout authors page is out of date.  The linux port maintainer, JonoF, [maintains a page here](http://www.jonof.id.au/kenutils) now.

I have to admit to not ever having used it.  Good luck!

Comment: `pngquant` doesn't preserve alpha channel. It produces the same output as GIMP.

Comment: `pngout` will not cooperate - `Unable to compress further: copying original file`

Comment: wow.  can you make this image available somewhere?  I'd like to take a crack at it.

Comment: Just take any PNG32 image, I'm actually using one of the icons from Silk iconset - http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/.

Comment: All the icons in famfamfam_silk_icons_v013.zip appear to be 8-bit.  I'm having trouble finding a 32 bit image on the web.  Don't want to make one myself using the tools that are causing your grief as that's not likely a valid test.

Comment: found a 32bit image with I think every possible transparency levle set: http://www.virtualmechanics.com/support/tutorials-spinnerpro/image/obj4120geo2655shd297pg5p6.png.  Now I see your problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [pngquant](http://pngquant.org), but make sure you have version later than 1.6. The latest version has very good quantizer that will beat PHP's libGD by far, in every case.

Debian wheezy still contains a *13-year-old version* that has low quality output. There's a [good pngquant package](http://packages.debian.org/experimental/graphics/pngquant) for Debian experimental, and most other Linux distros.

If your distro has only outdated `pngquant`, then use `pngnq` instead.